# Static linking with dylib ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, macos, qt, linker, gcc4.9

I'm compiling a qt5 c++ project with gnu49 compile while linking with few other dylibs (armadillo,boost libs etc.) on Mac OSX El Captitan with c++11 flag and usual qt framework flags. The project compiles fine but to make it more portable on few other machines I'm trying to statically link few dynamic libraries. 
I added -static flag before the (to be statically linked) library (e.g `-static -lboost_thread`) as described here.

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-05/msg00517.html

However, I get the following error.

> ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I verified that the error comes only while trying to link statically and not with dynamic linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC's `-static` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), which you are applying, is non-positional. It enforces
static linkage of all libraries. Your linkage then fails because your system has no static version of `libcrt0.o`

You may be confusing GCC's `static` option with [`ld`'s `-static` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) (synonyms: `-Bstatic`, `-dn` `-non_shared`),
which *is* positional. It affects only *subsequent* libraries on the commandline. It is the inverse of
the linker's `-Bdynamic` option (synonyms: `-dy`, `-call_shared`).

So to link only libraries `-lfoo`, `-lbar`... statically, via GCC, you can pass `-Bstatic` through to the
linker just before you mention them and `-Bdynamic` just after them:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Do not omit the final `-Wl,-Bdynamic`, even if `-lbar` is the last of your libraries, because GCC quietly appends standard libraries
to your linkage (as you have found).